# My iphone 4s as low heap limit ..app crash's after 174 mb usage?

Tags: ios, iphone

I had interesting problem, I am creating app for iphone 4s, so i am debugging on my iphone 4s , app crashes after memory reaches 194 mb..., it's working fine on iphone 4, i checked memory limit for both phones. Iphone 4 show 300 mb limit to crash , where my Iphone 4s shows 174 mb limit to get crash .

why is it so..?

Comment: What are other apps are open?  What's going on in your app when it does crash?  What does the debugger actually say?

Comment: No other apps are opened..xcode say exiting app because of memory pressure..It is working fine on iphone 4..

Comment: If I'm asking you questions in comment, that means the question itself likely needs a lot more detail.  Edit a lot more details about the crash into the question.

Comment: My question is not about crash..i want to know why my iphone 4s has low heap limit of 174 mb where it should be 300 mb..

Comment: Then you're at the wrong website.  StackOverflow is Q&A website for programming questions and answers and this is a purely hardware question.

Comment: Thanks you..I want to know whether any one faced this issue..

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory issue. So, free memory in your iPhone 4s might be less than iPhone 4.